# How to deserialize a TOML table containing an array of tables

Tags: rust, toml

Take the following TOML data:

```
[[items]]
foo = 10
bar = 100

[[items]]
foo = 12
bar = 144
```

And the following rust code:

```rust
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use toml::from_str;
use toml::value::Table;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    foo: String,
    bar: String
}

fn main() {
    let items_string: &str = "[[items]]\nfoo = 10\nbar = 100\n\n[[items]]\nfoo = 12\nbar = 144\n";
    let items_table: Table = from_str(items_string).unwrap();
    let items: Vec<Item> = items_table["items"].as_array().unwrap().to_vec();
    // Uncomment this line to print the table
    // println!("{:?}", items_table);
}
```

As you can see by yourself, the program [does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bfd309aa10916d82c08e1fe6f7253c9), giving this error in return:

> expected struct `Item`, found enum `toml::value::Value`

I understand its meaning, but I don't know how I could solve this and achieve what I wanted to do in the first place: cast a child array of a parent table into an array of structs and NOT into an array of tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse into the pre-defined TOML types such as `Table`, but these types don't know about types outside of the pre-defined ones. Those types are mostly used when the actual type of the data is unknown, or unimportant.

In your case that means that the TOML `Table` type doesn't know about your `Item` type and cannot be made to know about it.

However you can easily parse into a different type:

```rust
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use toml::from_str;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Item {
    foo: u64,
    bar: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let items_string: &str = "[[items]]\nfoo = 10\nbar = 100\n\n[[items]]\nfoo = 12\nbar = 144\n";
    let items_table: HashMap<String, Vec<Item>> = from_str(items_string).unwrap();
    let items: &[Item] = &items_table["items"];

    println!("{:?}", items_table);
    println!("{:?}", items);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=082918cab0363e4021c942fb2f038654))

Comment: I'd usually [define another struct instead of using a hash map](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2774b81d322f5dba3ad45e4443438df1).

Comment: @SvenMarnach that would depend on whether the keys are known at compile-time which isn't specified in the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I don't know the table names at compile time! So predefined structs don't work... it wasn't obvious from the doc if this was possible or not.